# what is the correct object orientated way to get a list of custom objects

Tags: c#, class

Lets say I have a user object in an external class. I'd then like to get all users.

I've read elsewhere that static methods should tend to be avoided. so calling something along the lines of `List<User> usrs = User.GetAllUsers()` should be avoided.

Would the best practice therefore be to do

```
User u = new User();
List<User> usrs = u.GetAllUsers();
```

it seems silly to have to create a new object and putting it in memory for the sake of calling a whole new list of objects altogether.

Comment: I would not say they should be avoided... strongly depends on what the actual problem is

Comment: what about this problem :)

Comment: Where are you getting the `User` instances from? It seems to me like you'd want something like a `UserRepository` from where you get your `User`objects.

Comment: we use a business layer, which in turn calls entity framework then exposes the class to the UI layer.

Comment: @LiamHT it's fine you should use `List<User> usrs = User.GetAllUsers();`.

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't make sense. Why would your single User object be used to GetAllUsers? Is there any reason you want to do this?

Comment: thats the point of my post. it seemed silly, but I've been reading to avoid static methods as a rule of thumb. and the static method would make sense to return the list as it is still contextually related to the user class

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would have something like a `UserRepository` which manages your `User` objects and takes care of adding, deleting, searching etc. your users.

From there you would get a list of your users. Something like:

```
class UserRepository
{
    // if you don't want to expose properties but only access them via method calls...
    private List<User> Users { get; }

    public UserRepository()
    {
        // get Users from Database or any other source...
        Users = db.Users;
    }

    public List<User> GetAllUsers()
    {
        return Users;
    }

    public void AddUser(User u)
    {
        Users.Add(u);
    }
}
```

And in your app you'd do something like this:

```
var userRep = new UserRepository();
var users = userRep.GetAllUsers();
```

You could argue about making the repository a static class if you'll just have one.

Comment: I disagree about validation part. Repositories should not care about validation IMO.

Comment: @Steve That's certainly valid criticism, I just added the method as an example anyway, so I'll remove that to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no reason to avoid static methods by default. Their purpose is to expose methods that can act on their own and don't need any other object data from the same logical class.

Microsoft uses static methods a lot, for example in the System.Math namespace:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.aspx

In your example, GetAllUsers() can be made static if you do not plan to add extra fields or methods to this collection of users in the future. If you do want this,  it might be better to create a `UserCollection` class which represents a list of users.

```
   public class UserCollection : Collection<User>
    {
        public IEnumerable GetAll()
        {
            return this.AsEnumerable();
        }

        public void MyFutureMethod()
        {
            //something you might want to do later on :-)
        }
    }
```

Comment: the only criticism of that example is that its a whole new class for one type, which is still in reality, just a user. the whole point of the system.math class is that it acts as methods with a general purpose. like a utility class. from what i understand atleast

Comment: Making a new class of the usercollection makes sense when you look at the collection of users as a new entity.The same pattern can be found in System.Web.Ui. Each control has a ControlCollection:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.controlcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

> I've read elsewhere that static methods should tend to be avoided.

Static methods are not bad per se. There are many valid use cases, such as mathematical helper functions or static factories.

However, **stateful** static methods may be problematic. These are essentially just global variables or singletons in disguise – with all their associated problems. They are also difficult to test.